# arrow on bottom right side in Ubuntu budgie

Tags: 18.04, lts, budgie, ubuntu-budgie

[image: screenshot]

what is the purpose of the arrow on bottom right side in Ubuntu budgie. how to remove it.
it go away after restart and comes back after sometimes. i don't think i have installed/added anything for the arrow and also it always on top of all programs .

Comment: I don't even see a bottom panel, do you have one? Also: could you test if it appears after connecting a device?

Answer (score 0):

You might have a "Drop by" applet in your panel. To remove it go to your **desktop-settings** > **Panels** | look for a "Popup menu for usb drives" applet and remove it.